# Prototype - Element with styleclass in element with an id?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

First of all: I'm new to Prototype JS Framework!
Until now I worked with jQuery.
In jQuery I am able to get an element by coding:

```
$('#myitemid .myitemclass').val()
```

html:

```
<div id="myitemid">
    <input type="text" class="notmyclass" />
    <input type="text" class="myitemclass" />
    <input type="text" class="notmyclass" />
</div>
```

But how to do this in prototype?
I tried to code:

```
$('myitemid .myitemclass').value
```

but this won't work.
Can U help me plz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [$$](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollardollar.html) which returns all elements in the document that match the provided CSS selectors.

```
var elemValue = $$('#myitemid input.myitemclass')[0].getValue();
```

Also `input.myitemclass` is better than `.myitemclass` because it restricts search to input elements with class name .myitemclass.

Comment: THX! 
...input.myitemclass is better than .myitemclass... (like in jquery!)
Another question:
Thinking myitemclass is a div instead of an input. How can I change the html inside the div? (in jQuery it's like $('#id divclass').html())

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the named element `myitemid`, simply use `$('myitemid')`.  This is equivalent to `$('#myitemid')` or `document.getElementById('myitemid')`.  Your case is more complex, since you want to select a child of a named element.  In that case you want to first find the named element, then use a selector on it's children.

```
$('myitemid').select('input.myitemclass')
```

Then, to access it's value (since it's a form element), you can add `.getValue()`.

```
$('myitemid').select('input.myitemclass').getValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be faster

```
$("myitemid").down("input[class~=myitemclass]").value
```